# Question about Teamviewer and visible IP address

Tags: ip, account-security, teamviewer

I have read conflicting things about this and was hoping to get a definitive answer to my question which is this - If I am dialing in to an associate's computer via Teamveiwer, is there any way possible that my IP address can be detected or any other identifiable bits of information from my end (browser footprints, user agent, mac address, etc;)?

I would much appreciate your input, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Teamviewer connections are shoveled through the Teamviewer servers.  Otherwise, I wouldn't know how most client edge devices would know to route to a client using PAT/NAT.

But yeah, like the other answer stated, it would be straightforward to check the open connections yourself to inspect the IP handle.

As for your other questions.

> browser footprints

I'm not sure what you mean by this one.  Are you talking about referring website and general tracking information? I would suppose your best bet would be to browse in Incognito/Private mode or any of those specialty anti-tracking browsers.

> user agent

I wouldn't see how, but I suppose it is possible the teamviewer client could leak/expose this information, though I'm not sure what it'll get you outside of the client version.  All in all, I wouldn't count on that information to be confidential.

> mac address

MAC Addresses change as you hit each switch, Those MAC tables are how the switches forward the packets.  A cursory look, [this](http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2339639&seqNum=3) may help you understand.

Comment: You mean router not switch. Routers are changing the source and destination mac address, switches aren't.